# Is there a way to set automated responses in Azure AD for Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Within Azure AD is there a way to automate responses if someone in the organization tries to access a "blocked" application? For example, someone tries to use their account on SurveyMonkey, which we blocked in Azure AD, and we would like a message to appear that says "The approved application for surveys is MS Forms. Please reach out if there is a particular functionality that requires SurveyMonkey."

We currently have an application approval process in place but what is happening is that we have multiple users requesting the same application while we have an approved application that functions the same. Other examples would be to use OneNote instead of EverNote.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your users are using their Azure AD Credentials, then you could setup [User Consent Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#user-consent-settings) to not allow them to consent thereby requiring an admin to consent on their behalf.

But if they are using their personal credentials, you would have to block access via your corporate network firewall.